# SoapClient call difference between browser and php-cli execution

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have a simple php script with fallowing code included:

```
 $options = array(
            'uri'=>'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/',
            'style'=>SOAP_RPC,
            'use'=>SOAP_ENCODED,
            'soap_version'=>SOAP_1_1,
            'cache_wsdl'=>WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
            'connection_timeout'=>15,
            'trace'=>true,
            'encoding'=>'UTF-8',
            'exceptions'=>true
        );

        $client = new SoapClient($wsdl,$options);
```

When I am executing code via php-cli (CentOS 8) everything works like a charm. 
I can successfully connect to webservice and call methods, process responses etc.

When I am trying to execute script via browser I am getting an error:

*Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [WSDL] SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from 'http://xxx/services/Assets?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "http://xxx/services/Assets?wsdl" in /var/www/html/xxx.php:32 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/xxx.php(32): SoapClient->SoapClient('http://xxx....', Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/xxx.php on line 32*

Since php is executed on **server side** what is the difference between running the script directly on a server via php-cli and running the script from remote host indirectly via browser? PHP is executed **on** a webserver so it should not be a firewall/networking issue... right?

The webservice server I am trying to connect is on other host than my CentOS with apache/php, but there is no firewall/acl's between them. Route is properly configured (like I said, from php-cli everything works fine)

Comment: How are you running PHP? FPM, Apache, Built-in server? My guess is that host resolution works differently than CLI (which should pretty much do the same as the user executing the script)

Comment: @ArSeN I have fresh CentOS 8 installed with httpd/php/php-cli/php-soap from default repos. I have changed hostname to ip (for wsdl address) - no change.

Comment: So you are saying with IP it still works from CLI but not when executed with httpd and a browser, yes? In that case host resolution should not be the problem. Can you try and do something else but soap, e.g. a file_get_contents() on the wsdl and see if the problem repeats?

Comment: @ArSeN Yes, IP still works from CLI but not from browser. I have made super simple script with: echo file_get_contents('http://[ip]/services/Assets?wsdl'); In CLI it returns WSDL while in browser in returns nothing (I have checked also webpage code)... why? I should allow remote calls in httpd.conf or sth?

Comment: ps. I have checked my php.ini and I have `allow_url_fopen = On`. I have set `error_reporting(E_ALL);` and `ini_set('display_errors', '1');` Now I am getting an error `Warning: file_get_contents(http://[ip]/services/Assets?wsdl): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/xxx.php on line 4`

Comment: ps2. ok my idea now is that it probably is related somehow with user rights. When calling a php-cli I am running it as a root while via browser as a apache user. I have made `chmod 777 xxx.php` and (not needed with 777 but still...) `chown apache:apache xxx.php`- no chenge still Permission denied. These files are cached somewhere? Maybe apache is not able to cache them?

Answer (score 1):

SELinux that was causing the problem

`setsebool -P httpd_can_network_connect 1`

made the magic trick! :)

Thank You @ArSeN for good directions!!